# C++ makefile compilation dependent library

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile, static-libraries

It may be a noob question, but I'm really trying to figure it out: I have my C++ project that make uses of other libraries (ex. log4cplus, and getopt_pp). I developed it under eclipse, and now I'm configuring it with autotools to distribuite it with a makefile and a configure script to make sure that everyone can compile it.
My question is: how can I obtain that calling `./configure` or `./make` will automatically compile&install the static libraries in the end user system?

- What is the best way to do this?
- What is the best path to install the library?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is not to do this at all. Instead, you should document (in the install documentation) that your application/library depends on some other libraries (and preferably also which version you tested it with) and your `configure` script should check for the presence of these dependencies.

The reasons are:

- There are vast differences between systems where such libraries should be located. Your scripts will never do it correctly for everyone.
- The user may already have a compatible version installed and may prefer to use that one over the version that might come bundled with your software.
- Linking such libraries statically into an application is actually quite rare nowadays. All major compilers default to dynamic linking. This makes it even more likely that the user already has a version of those libraries installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are shipping the libraries along with your project (as opposed to distributing them independently and requiring the user to ensure they are installed), then you'll probably want to put those libraries in their own directories inside your project, and in your `configure.ac` make sure it's aware of those sub directories by adding the `Makefile` output targets to `AC_OUTPUT`, ie something like

`AC_OUTPUT(Makefile log4cplus/Makefile getopt_pp/Makefile yourprogramsrc/Makefile)`

then in your root level `Makefile.am`, let it know about your new subdirs, ie

`SUBDIRS=log4cplus getopt_pp yourprogramsrc`

then ensure your include flags and linker flags are setup right to point to the libraries you're including.